# How to make changes in MutableLivedata<List<Obj>> (removing item + addin a new item) from UI?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

So, I need so that after item is swiped, the item is removed from current mlist, and a new item is fetched from DB and
added to the list at the end fo it.

1. Where and what I need to write to remove Item;
2. Where and what I need to write to change current mList by adding a new item from RoomDB? (getPerson() method is in ViewModel)

In Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :statusname ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3")
Single<List<Person>> getThreePersons(String statusname);

@Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :statusname ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
Single<List<Person>> getPerson(String statusname);
```

In Repo:

```
PersonRepository(Application application) {
    PersonRoomDatabase db = PersonRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mPersonDao = db.PersonDao();
    mThreePersons = mPersonDao.getThreePersons(MUDAK);
    mPerson = mPersonDao.getPerson(MUDAK);
}
Single<List<Person>> getThreePersons() {return mThreePersons;} // to get 3 persons to initially fulfill the working List<>
Single<List<Person>> getPerson() {return mPerson;}   // to get 1 person from Romm DB
```

In ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    private CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();
    private Single<List<Person>> mThreePersons;     
    private Single<List<Person>> mPerson;      
    private ArrayList<Person> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> mListLivedata = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
        mThreePersons = mRepository.getThreePersons();
        mPerson = mRepository.getPerson(); 

        mThreePersons.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Person>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        composite.add(d);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Person> people) {
                        mList.addAll(people);
                        mListLivedata.setValue(mList); // here I get 3 Persons from RoomDB to fill the list, evrthing works OK
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(application, "OnError called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    LiveData<List<Person>> getListLivedata() {
        return mListLivedata;
    }
}
```

In Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CardStackListener {
    private CardStackView personCardStackView;
    private PersonAdapter personAdapter;
    private CardStackLayoutManager personCardStackLayoutManager;
    private PersonViewModel personViewModel;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mudakViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()))
            .get(PersonViewModel.class);
        mudakViewModel.getListLivedata().observe(this, personList -> {
        mudakAdapter.submitList(personList);
    });
    personCardStackView = findViewById(R.id.card_stack_view);
    personCardStackLayoutManager = new CardStackLayoutManager(this, this);
    personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(new PersonAdapter.PersonDiff()); 
    personCardStackView.setLayoutManager(personCardStackLayoutManager);
    personCardStackView.setAdapter(personAdapter);
    // other methods
}
public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
    //some methods updating current item. After onSwiped, when item has gone beyond the screen onCardDisappeared is called, see below
}
public void onCardDisappeared(View view, int position) {
    mudakCurrentPerson = mudakAdapter.getPersonAt(position);
    // here I need to call method for 1)removing swiped <Item> from LiveData<List<...>> and 2)adding a new random <Item> from-
    // from RoomDB, using getPerson() method which is initialized in ViewModel already
}
```

Something from Adapter (if needeed):

```
public class MudakAdapter extends ListAdapter<Person, MudakAdapter.MudakViewHolder> {
    protected MudakAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Person> diffCallback) {
        super(diffCallback);
    }
    // methods, holder etc ......
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MudakViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Person currentPerson = getItem(position);
            holder.mName.setText(currentPerson.getName());
            holder.mStatus.setText(currentPerson.getStatus());
        }


        public Person getPersonAt(int position) {
            return getItem(position);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LiveDataReactiveStreams. It allows you to use RxJava and LiveData together. From your Room Database return Flowable instead of single. for example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :statusname ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
Flowable<List<Person>> getPerson(String statusname);
```

Then in your ViewModel, you can convert this flowable into LiveData using LiveDataReactiveStreams. see the example below:

```
LiveData<List<Person>> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(respository.getPerson());
```

Now whenever a new item is added or the existing item is deleted, the List will be automatically emitted by the flowable to the LiveData which you can observe in your UI.

Add this in your Gradle. Replace <specific_version> with the latest version.

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:<specific_version>"
```

You can read more about LiveDataReactiveStreams [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/livedatareactivestreams-where-rxjava-meets-livedata/).

Comment: Thank you very much, yet I still don't understand how to remove/add item to the list which UI is observing..

Comment: my adapter does not understand which item is deleted by swipe. When I do swipe, current <Person> is updated and deleted; but when I swipe next, <Person> is updated and deleted from <List>, but not from View; at the same time the third <Person> is deleted from View (because adapter tries to find item #1 but not #0, while after deleting item #0, item #1 has become item #0, and respectively item #2 has become item #1, but adapter doesn't know this, I don't understand how to synchronize this..)